# Renderer2 enable/disabled Mat-radio-button-group

Tags: angular

I have a mat-radio-button-group that starts of as disabled, and want to programatically change the disabled value

```
@ViewChild('voice_card_choices') voiceCardChoices: ElementRef; 

this.renderer.setProperty(this.voiceCardChoices, 'disabled', false); // Doesn't work
this.voiceCardChoices.disabled = false; // Doesn't work, just creates a new property called disabled on the object
this.voiceCardChoices.nativeElement.disabled = false; //Doesn't work, same case as above
```

Tried using both `Renderer2` and just the `ElementRef` and the `nativeElement`, nothing seems to work

Answer (score 2):

If you change `ElementRef` to `MatRadioButton` or `MatRadioButtonGroup` it work

This code work without render

```
constructor(public renderer: Renderer2) {} 
@ViewChild('voice_card_choices') voiceCardChoices: MatRadioButton || ElementRef ; 

functionToDisableDropDown() {
  this.voiceCardChoices.disabled = true;
}
```

Hope useful

Comment: MatRadioButton || ElementRef this doesn't compile, do I need the ` || ElementRef`, asking because without it, seems to not be working.

Comment: You don't need elementref